# Detect when a line break has been erased inside a UITextView - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

Is there any way I can detect when a line break has been erased insde a UITextView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the delegate

```
-(BOOL)textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:
```

If a delete occurs, you will have replacementText with length 0, and you can look at the textView.text at range to see what was deleted:

```
[textView.text substringWithRange:range]
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could compare that string with @"\n" or something to know if it's a line break which was erased. How do I really know if it shows @"" when a line break was erased?